# knockout - how to compute total price of selected services for each contact and overall price for all contacts

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a knockout based form that I want to compute total price of selected services for each contact.. and overall price for all contacts.

Here's my live DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/yzmcD/3/

for example:

---

```
 - First Name: John
 - Last Name: Carter
 - Selected Services:
   - Service One (price: 30 $)
   - Service Two (price: 10 $)
 - Debt: 40 $
```

---

```
 - First Name: Arnold
 - Last Name: Cruise
 - Selected Services:
   - Service One (price: 20 $)
   - Service Two (price: 10 $)
   - Service Three (price: 30 $)
 - Debt: 60 $
```

---

**Total: 100 $**

---

Comment: Here's my live DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/yzmcD/3/

Comment: Have you had a look at creating a `computed` observable which calculates the total price? When a `computed` observable in knockout reads the value of an observable (or observable array, or another computed) it also subscribes to changes in that observable. When any of the observables which a computed has subscribed to changes the computed will recalculate its value. I suggest going through the tutorials at http://learn.knockoutjs.com/ since they are very good and the "Working with Lists and Collections" tutorial will, among other things, help you learn to use `computed` observables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems:

- `selectedId` of `Catalog` does not store just the service Id. I prefer the variable holding the service object, it should be named to reflect that.
- `Catalog` should either not store `selectedId` or you shouldn't store `Catalog` objects as a `service` of a contact. If this data were to be serialized to `JSON`, as is, you'd get a lot of unnecessary data duplication.
- Since you are creating an object to represent a contact in multiple places, create a `Contact` function to encapsulate that. This will also allow for a container to hold the computed to calculate the total of services per `Contact`

  ```
  function Contact(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.debt = data.debt,
    self.firstName = data.firstName,
    self.lastName = data.lastName,
    self.services = ko.observableArray(data.services),
    self.total = ko.computed(function () {
      var total = 0;
      var serviceItems = self.services()
      ko.utils.arrayForEach(serviceItems, function (service) {
        if (service.selectedId()) {
          total += parseInt(service.selectedId().price);
        }
      })
      return total;
    })
  }
  ```
- Finally, the `ContactsModel` needs a computed to calculate the total across all contacts

  ```
  self.contactsTotal = ko.computed(function () {
    var total = 0;
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.contacts(), function (contact) {
      total += contact.total();
    })
    return total;
  })
  ```

I added the necessary computed observables to [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/W23UT/).
You'll also need to consider the impact of chaining computed observable dependencies this way. Very large data would cause a lot of array processing. If that were to ever become an issue you'd want to change to an approach that sums once and then increments/decrements that sum with each data modification.

Comment: Thank You, Origineil. Your answer was so useful for me. You are great! Thanks Again!